# Complex identity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I am struggling with a proof of following identity
$$ 1-z^m=\prod_{k=1}^m (1-\omega_kz)$$
where $\omega_k=e^{\frac{2\pi k}{m}i}$ for $k=1,2,\dotsc m$ are roots of unity and $z$ is a complex number. I've started with expanding RHS and I get
$$1-z\sum_{j=1}^m \omega_j+z^2\sum_{\substack{   j=1 \\
                            k<j}}^m \omega_j\omega_k- \dots+(-1)^mz^m\prod_{j=1}^m\omega_j$$
Then I've proved that sum of roots of unity equals 0 and the product of roots of unity equals 1, but I don't know how to deal with those mixed sums.

I'll be grateful for any clues.

Comment: Replace $z$ by $1/w$ and multiply both sides by $w^n$. You get $w^n-1=\prod_{k=1}^{m}(w-\omega_k)$. This one is true by definition of $\omega_k$. So, your equation is true for all $z\neq0$. For $z=0$ you get $1=1$.

Comment: Hint: show that the difference is a polynomial of degree $<m$ in $z$. Can you find obvious roots?

Answer (score 0):

If $\omega$ is a root, then so is $\overline{\omega}$, except for $\omega=1$ and $\omega=-1$. $\omega=-1$ is only a root for even $m$, and as $\omega\overline{\omega}=1$, the product of the roots of unity is $(-1)^{m-1}$.

Next, it is fairly simple to prove that:

$$\sum_{j=1}^m \omega_j^n=0$$

for any $1\le n<m$, and $m>1$.

Then note that:

$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^m \omega_j\right)^2=\sum_{j=1}^m \omega_j^2+2\sum_{1\le i< j\le m} \omega_i\omega_j$$

so that $\sum_\limits{1\le i< j\le m} \omega_i\omega_j=0$.

The rest follow similarly, noting that:

$$\sum_{j=1}^m \omega_j^m=m$$

Comment: Thank you, I understood this example, but I am not sure how it works for products of three (and more) roots. When I considered  third power of sum of roots for $m=3$ I get  extra terms such as $\omega_k^2\omega_j$. I suppose, that sum equals to 0, but I don't know why.